# Multi-column subfloats with subfig

Tags: subfloats, multicol

I have to use `subfig` instead of `subcaption` because the style I have to use redefines the look of captions and I can't change that. Given this constraint, how do I use `multicol` to make multiple-columns subfloats?

The problem is that this doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[inner caption]{
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \end{multicols}
}
\caption{outer caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

since it results in

> ```
>  ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
> ```

(BTW, "something's wrong" is the stupidest error message I've ever seen...)

My ultimate goal is to put two `bussproof` proof trees side-by-side, and then more, wider proof trees in single column below it; all in the same single `subfloat`.

Comment: @Zarko: Two pictures next to each other on one line, then a third picture in a second line, and these three together should share one sub-caption; then more pictures with a second shared sub-caption; then some more, and so on. And then the whole thing would also have its own caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using minipage inside the subfigure?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[inner caption]{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
}

\subfloat[inner caption2]{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[2]
  \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}
}
\caption{outer caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]